# Java ExecutorService as implementation detail

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I'm working on a little library that invokes a callback on each member of a set of Objects. Ideally I want these tasks to be concurrent, so I create an ExecutorService inside my class. It's a private field, ideally the user needn't know that my class has an ExecutorService.

But then, I read that ExecutorServices need to be `shutdown()` after use or the program won't exit. However, a private ExecutorService is created as part of a static initializer in my library. My library doesn't know when the app is done doing work, so it can't call `shutdown()` on the ExecutorService. And the library user may not know the ExecutorService exists, and even if they did, they couldn't call `shutdown()` on it, as it is private.

How do I resolve this dilemma?

Comment: since you use static initializer, you have to expose pubic static method to perform explicit tear down.

Comment: I would suggest following approach a. Create a public method in your library which is able to shutdown the executor service. Since, executerService is being initialised in a static block, that method can be made static. In your application code, you can add Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() which invokes the library method to stop the  executor service.

Comment: `But then, I read that ExecutorServices need to be shutdown()` - that is not exactly correct. If you provided ThreadFactory during ExecutirService creation which set daemon flag to true, you should be fine (assuming that executor is still running some tasks, otherwise it doesn't matter at all)

Comment: @akshayapandey : shutdown hooks are evil, mostly in OSGi/J2EE containers where they would not be run as expected.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach might be to have the user of your library inject (and manage) a `ExecutorService`. Your library is not in the best position to decide what kind of service to use (e.g. how many threads to use). This decision is ultimately one of the users of your library, who have a better understanding of the overall life-cycle of the application and in what kind of environment it is deployed.